# Does Linux / GCC have file sharing allow-deny type support?

Tags: linux, fcntl

Back in DOS, Borland C/C++ you had `O_DENYxxx` flags available on `open()`.  On MS Visual Studio / Windows you have `sopen()`, some flavors of `open()` have `O_SHARE_xxxx` flags available (ibm docs for example).  But I can't seem to find what Linux has available that works similarly?

Comment: What do `O_DENYxxx` flags do? Is there any reference available?

Comment: `O_DENYALL`, `O_DENYREAD`, `O_DENYWRITE`, `O_DENYNONE`, sharing mode.  Which were for the int 21h function 0x3D (61) in DOS.

Comment: http://members.tripod.com/vitaly_Filatov/ng/tc/tc_000.199.html - so if one process opens the file with O_DENYALL, and then some other process opens the file, the other process gets EACCESS? This looks like a normal file locking, like `flock` or like `F_WRLCK` from posix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Linux doesn't have any of these flags.  In general on Unix systems, any process with adequate permissions may perform any permitted operation on a file at any time.

There are, however, locking facilities, both with `fcntl` and with `flock`, that allow cooperating processes to take read and write locks on a file or parts of it to prevent unintentional conflicts.  There *is* mandatory locking that can be done with `fcntl`, but it is unreliable and deprecated as of kernel 4.5; you can see the `fcntl(2)` man page for more details.  If your program will ever run over NFS, `fcntl` is preferred for locking, because `flock` doesn't work there.

Alternatively, if you want a simpler interface, you can use something like [liblockfile](https://github.com/miquels/liblockfile), which provides a straightforward, NFS-safe interface for locking.

In general, the sharing locking available on DOS and Windows is considered a bad idea on Unix because it prevents processes from doing things like renaming over files or other operations which are widely expected to be available and succeed.